# Determine if $X=\{f\in C^1[0,1] | f(0)=f'(0)\}$ is complete WRT $||.||_{\infty}$ norm and show that $X$ is infinite dimensional.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

I'm having trouble determining if $X$ is complete WRT $||.||_{\infty}$ norm. I know that in order to show that I need to take a Cauchy sequence and show that it has a limit in my space $X$ or find a Cauchy sequence of functions which satisfy $f(0)=f'(0)$ and which limit lies outside of $X$. I tried but was unable to find a counter example, therefore I believe the statement to be true, however I am not sure exactly how to go about proving it.

So far I was able to prove that any $g\in X$ is of the form $f(0)+\int_0^xf(y)dy$ where $f\in C[0,1]$ if it helps.

would really appreciate it if somebody could show me how to prove of disprove this statement. Thanks

Comment: It is probably not complete for the $||.||_{\infty}$ norm but it is complete for a norm that sees the derivative, for instance $||f|| = ||f||_{\infty} + ||f'||_{\infty}$. With this norm $\mathcal{C}^1$ is in fact complete, now you condition is closed. As a counter example take a sequence of function on $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ in $\mathcal{C}^1$ that conveges for the $\infty$ norm to some non derivable function, then extend arbitrarily these functions to $[0,1]$ so that the sequence converge on $[0,1]$ and satisfies the condition (at least I hope something like that is possible).

Comment: that is what I was thinking. Because like you said it is complete in that norm and if $X$ was finite dimensional then it would be complete in the supp norm aswell and since it isnt it must be infinite dimension. That was how i wanted to prove the last part but still cant quite figure out the first part

Comment: For the infinite dimensional part you have two easy ways to do it. 1.) Pick nonzero smooth functions with support in $(1/(n+1),1/n)$, then they are linearly independent and in your space (to construct such functions, start with a nonzero function $f$ with compact support and extend it by zero to a function $\tilde{f}$ the whole real axis. Then find suitable scalars $a, b$ and consider $g(x)=\tilde{f}(ax+b)$.) 2.) All finite dimensional spaces are complete and thus yours cannot be finite dimensional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not complete.

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f_n\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}nx^2&\text{ if }x<\frac1{2n}\\x-\frac1{4n}&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Clearly, each $f_n$ belongs to $X$. But, in $\bigl(C^1[0,1],\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty\bigr)$, the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $f(x)=x$. And $f\notin X$. So, $X$ is not a closed subspace of $C^1[0,1]$ and therefore it is not complete. Or you can say that $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence of elements of $X$ which does not converge in $X$.

Comment: Thank you. Might I just ask how you went about finding a counter example? Or is this some known thing

Comment: No, it is not a known thing. I tried a few thing and I came up with this example.